# How to find Type of triangle(length of three sides are given) using nested case in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, case-when

[image: Sample Table]

What Is wrobg in this MySQL query?
It is showing syntax error.

```sql
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN A = B
        CASE
            WHEN A = C THEN 'Equilateral'
            WHEN C < A + B THEN 'Isosceles'
            ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
        END
    WHEN B = C
        CASE
            WHEN A < B + C THEN 'Isosceles'
            ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
        END
    WHEN A + B > C AND A + C > B AND B + C > A THEN 'Scalene'
    ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
END
FROM TRIANGLES;
```

Comment: please don't post images for code and data see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @nbk but how am I supposed to show sample table then?

Comment: you put the text and number in text form or you create a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add also a then for that purpose

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN A = B
    THEN
        CASE
            WHEN A = C THEN 'Equilateral'
            WHEN C < A + B THEN 'Isosceles'
            ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
        END
    WHEN B = C
    THEN
        CASE
            WHEN A < B + C THEN 'Isosceles'
            ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
        END
    WHEN A + B > C AND A + C > B AND B + C > A THEN 'Scalene'
    ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
END
FROM TRIANGLES;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to nest `case` expressions:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN A = B AND A = C THEN 'Equilateral'
             WHEN A = B AND C < A + B THEN 'Isosceles'
             WHEN A = B THEN 'Not A Triangle'
             WHEN B = C AND A < B + C THEN 'Isosceles'
             WHEN B = C THEN 'Not A Triangle'
             WHEN A + B > C AND A + C > B AND B + C > A THEN 'Scalene'
             ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
        END) as type
FROM TRIANGLES;
```

Comment: @Insane_ banda . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: No....op just answered it the way I wanted to solve it. Yours is good as well. Sorry if that was rude.

Comment: @Insane_banda . . . I generally think avoiding nesting of `case` expressions is a good thing, which is why I answered.